# OpenX asynchronous Tags

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ads, openx

Im trying to implement asynchronous ads in OpenX but am struggling with the documentation. Looking at example 26,

```
var OX_ads = OX_ads || [];
OX_ads.push({
   "slot_id":"placeholderId",
   "auid":"8",
   "tid":"4",
   "tg":"_blank",
   "r":"http://redirect.clicks.to.here/landing.html",
   "rd":"120",
   "rm":"2",
   "imp_beacon":"HTML for client-side impression beacon",
   "fallback":"HTML for client-side fallback"
});
```

It isnt clear what the parameters that can be passed are, and there is a javascript tag library
src="http://d.example.com/w/1.0/jstag"

But it doesnt say if this file has to be set up? Would be grateful for any advice from people who have gone through this.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching on the internet, I found out this link, from where we could get the 'jstag' file. 
Not absolutely sure if this is the way to go, but nevertheless it works.
Try adding this link src="http://uk-ads.openx.net/w/1.0/jstag" in place of the src="http://d.example.com/w/1.0/jstag".

Also to get a detailed explanation of what those variables are for, check out this link:
http://www.openx.com/docs/openx_help_center/content/adtagguide_parameters_openxadtag_parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for the parameters list, I think the jstag is generated from somewhere as "http://uk-ads.openx.net/w/1.0/jstag" is noted as gateway in code..